# In place edit for aligning column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh

I want to align the column of the following file.

```
cat input.dat 
0.1     0.22474401451476203     0.22474401451476203     0.22468184471725106     0.22474401451476203     0.22474466451476202
0.15000000000000002     0.09328229408835575     0.09328229408835575     0.09323107184876382     0.09328229408835575     0.09328294408835575
0.2     0.04700471936101653     0.04700471936101653     0.04696126453738079     0.04700471936101653     0.04700536936101653
0.25    0.025562449852510022    0.025562449852510022    0.025525019904759787    0.025562449852510022    0.02556309985251002
0.30000000000000004     0.013916483625141736    0.013916483625141736    0.013883976359424946    0.013916483625141736    0.013917133625141737
0.35    0.006918972749219993    0.006918972749219993    0.0068906275518585275   0.006918972749219993    0.006919622749219994
0.4     0.0024319065284844395   0.0024319065284844395   0.002407166678723833    0.0024319065284844395   0.0024325565284844396
0.45000000000000007     -0.0005564879581991863  -0.0005564879581991863  -0.0005780476659970637  -0.0005564879581991863  -0.0005558379581991862
0.5     -0.0025717430483357794  -0.0025717430483357794  -0.0025904580222108962  -0.0025717430483357794  -0.0025710930483357794
```

I can do like (and expected output) :

```
cat input.dat | column -t


0.1                  0.22474401451476203     0.22474401451476203     0.22468184471725106     0.22474401451476203     0.22474466451476202
0.15000000000000002  0.09328229408835575     0.09328229408835575     0.09323107184876382     0.09328229408835575     0.09328294408835575
0.2                  0.04700471936101653     0.04700471936101653     0.04696126453738079     0.04700471936101653     0.04700536936101653
0.25                 0.025562449852510022    0.025562449852510022    0.025525019904759787    0.025562449852510022    0.02556309985251002
0.30000000000000004  0.013916483625141736    0.013916483625141736    0.013883976359424946    0.013916483625141736    0.013917133625141737
0.35                 0.006918972749219993    0.006918972749219993    0.0068906275518585275   0.006918972749219993    0.006919622749219994
0.4                  0.0024319065284844395   0.0024319065284844395   0.002407166678723833    0.0024319065284844395   0.0024325565284844396
0.45000000000000007  -0.0005564879581991863  -0.0005564879581991863  -0.0005780476659970637  -0.0005564879581991863  -0.0005558379581991862
0.5                  -0.0025717430483357794  -0.0025717430483357794  -0.0025904580222108962  -0.0025717430483357794  -0.0025710930483357794
```

But I was looking for `inplace` solution (similar to `sed -i`).

Of course I can rename the file to something etc.

```
    cat input.dat | column -t > output.dat 
    mv output.dat input.dat
```

But I want to know if there is better solution to this.

Comment: What should the modified file look like?

Comment: @Shawn see the edit

Comment: `sed -i` is not a real in-place solution. It creates a file next to your original file then overwrites, just like you did.

Comment: There's a `moreutils` package that includes the `sponge` tool that lets you edit anything in-place. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207919/sponge-from-moreutils-whats-the-difference-to-shell-redirect-useful-examples). The simplification it offers isn't huge though, so it's up to you to decide whether it's worth installing a package that isn't default on any distribution I'm familiar with.

Comment: Why is it important to you that the tool you call creates and copies the temp file (as happens with `sed -i`, `perl -i`, `awk -i inplace`, etc.) vs if you do it yourself (e.g. `sed 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`)? Asking for that usually elicits an "ugh, why?" response on the forum, like asking for a "one-liner", but maybe you have a reason for it that we could help with?

Comment: @EdMorton, well there is nothing wrong with creating temporary file and them moving it to the desired output file. My reason may be little bit silly. I am running shell commands inside `Mathematica`. And there somehow if I combine in a single line it does not work (don't ask me why). It simply can't process combined command. So I have to do in two steps instead which is annoying.

Comment: Good to know you have a reason. Why not ask a question about THAT and tag it with mathematica though?

Comment: @EdMorton, well my previous answer is not entirely true(just found out). Inside `Mathemetica` something like `column -t input.dat > tmp & mv tmp input.dat` works. Note the single use of `&` instead of double `&&`. The other thing is (to my experience) `Mathematica` does not like shell commands running through it.

Comment: However I still think a better solution to have an `inplace`  edit option. :)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if a single `&` inside mathematica means the same as a double `&&` in shell though. Any `inplace` solution is going to make your code dependent on non-standard tools and so non-portable so YMMV. It still sounds like tagging a question with mathematica so you get people who know/care about mathermatica chiming in on your real problem would be a reasonable idea.

Comment: Not that this is the question here but most likely the values `0.15000000000000002` are bogus due to floating point representation...

Answer (score 3):

in place of in place edit, you can follow this approach.

```
$ column -t file > temp && mv temp file
```

this function will mimic in place formatting

```
$ fip () { temp=$(mktemp) && column -t "$1" > $temp && mv $temp "$1"; }
$ fip file
```

Comment: well this is my current solution which I am using. This of course gives the expected output as it should be but I wanted something `inplace` solution if possible either with `column` or `sed` etc.

Comment: a bit safer might be `temp="$(mktemp)" && column -t "$1" > "$temp" && mv "$temp" "$1";`

Comment: wrt `$temp` vs `"$temp"` - quotes aren't something you add when you need to, they're something you remove when you need to, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. You don't need to remove the quotes in this case so they should be present around your variables.

Answer (score 2):

The wording *inplace editing* is generally misunderstood. An inplace editing would imply that you do not change the file on the disk. Most *inplace* solutions given by various tools, such as `sed -i` and `awk -i inplace`, are nothing more than a masked form of

```
$ tmpfile="$(mktemp)" && command file > "${tmpfile}" && mv "${tmpfile}" file
```

which make a temporary file/copy and then rename it to the original. The implementation is not necessarily this, but it will be similar. So you have to be aware that, in the end, there is a chance that you duplicate the data. This is especially cumbersome when operating on large files without enough disc space. You can easily check this by validating the inode number of the file before and after the operation. The only true inplace, is done using `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to improve it is by not making an useless use of cat. You can simply `column -t input.dat` instead of `cat input.dat | column -t`, so you get

```
column -t input.dat > output.dat 
mv output.dat input.dat
```

That command-block is analogous to what `sed -i` does ([see this answer by Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92907)), so there would be nothing else to be improved.

If you prefer an one-liner, the exact equivalent to the command-block is `column -t input.dat > output.dat; mv output.dat input.dat`. If you want to do the second command only if the first succeeds, then `column -t input.dat > output.dat && mv output.dat input.dat`, as @karakfa has already provided in his answer.

Comment: you do not need to do cat. `column -t <input.dat`

Comment: @DigvijayS Yeah, that is what I said (you don't even need the `<`).

Comment: @Quasímodo, `column -t input.dat` will only print it on screen but it will not change the `input.dat` no?

Comment: @Boogeyman Yes, you only need to substitute that `cat input.dat | column -t` with `column -t input.dat` in your last block, but keep the `> output.dat` bit.

Comment: Well, `cat input.dat |` part is redundant. But even without it its a two line solution or as @karakfa has mentioned one can combine that in a line. But I was wondering for a solution like `sed -i`,( not necessarily with `column -t`). It seems that `column` does not have inplace edit.

Comment: I edited the answer so that the one-liners options are there explained. But, indeed, the `column` manual provides no in-place option. The best you can do is to reproduce what a in-place would do, and that is by no means worse.

Comment: In this context `If you want to do the second command only if the first succeeds` isn't an option - you **always** want to do the second command only if the first succeeds or you'd zap your input file if the first command fails. So **always** use `&&` between the `cmd file > tmp` and the `mv tmp file`..